# Can't get PHP working on osx 10.8.2

Tags: php, apache, installation, osx-mountain-lion

I have tried to follow the many tutorials for setting up PHP that is native with OSX 10.8, but failed to accomplish it, and feel that I'm going to make it worse if I continue.  Here's the information I cant tell you (let me know if you need more info):

In terminal, typing `which php` results in `/usr/bin/php`

I have XCode 4.5.2 installed

I have Command Line Tools installed

I have XQuartz-2.7.4 installed

I have GCC 10.7 v2 installed

In finder, my `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` shows:
`info.php` and a folder `orig` containing `index.html.en`, `info.php`(I duplicated this to test the PHP running in a different scope - ¿maybe?, obviously didn't work), `PoweredByMacOSX.gif`, and `PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif`

These directories DO exist:

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/man/man1
```

`~/.pearrc` returns `-bash: /Users/me/.pearrc: No such file or directory`

I am running 10.8.2 on a rMBP

my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
. `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh ]; then
. `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh
fi
PS1='CANT SHOW YOU'
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump ]; then
. `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump
fi
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a         shell session *as a function*
export SCALING_SECRET_TOKEN="CANT SHOW YOU"
```

My `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

My user account conf `me.conf` located in `/etc/apache2/users`:

```
<Directory "/Users/me/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so  // I removed the # at the begining
//under <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
AllowOverride All    // changed to All from None
```

I have had this error:

```
Error: uncaught throw `Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.8 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d --with-iconv-dir=/usr --enable-dba --with-ndbm=/usr --enable-exif --enable-soap --enable-wddx --enable-ftp --enable-sockets --enable-zip --enable-pcntl --enable-shmop --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --with-zlib=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.7 --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-xmlrpc --with-kerberos=/usr --with-xsl=/usr --with-curl=/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.28.0 --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10 --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8 --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d --with-png-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.13 --with-gettext=/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.1.1 --with-snmp=/usr --with-libedit --mandir
```

and this one:

```
Error: uncaught throw `No available formula for zlib '
```

Comment: I don't know what's going on with ML, but if it's like previous versions it looks like you're really overdoing stuff!  On my machines from Leopard to Lion all it took was finding the httpd.conf file, removing the commenting out for the loadmodule php5.so line and restarting apache.  That should enable the Apple-supplied PHP, though it's missing a few important extensions.  You can get a more complete PHP install by installing the liip PHP package

Comment: Did you get this - or a similar - error when compilin (configuring) any other source package? It might be an issue introduced through a third party package like brew.

Comment: I tried brew after it didnt work not using any third party.